# Do we have access to storage folder file for download in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am storing some json files is storage folder,and converting all of them to pdf and storing in storge folder only.

I want to download the pdf now through ajax.

Is there anyway to make the storage folder file available publicly.

Comment: yes you can give access to folder, but why ? it contains your session files and caches and what not. Why not store file on some public directory ?

Comment: Hi Murtaza, yes I can store in public directory but I am performing some analysis on those file and can't keep those file in public directory due to confidentiality issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't open it for direct access, but i would suggest to use an function in your Controller like this:

```
public function getPdf() {

    $file = "XYZ/storage/download/info.pdf";
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type: application/pdf',
    );

    return \Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```